# Front-End and Back-End Selection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, django, database, backend

Pardon the vague question but I am having a difficult time deciding on the approach to a project based on self-interest.

I have a significant amount of Java and C background knowledge, however I am interested in beginning a web-development portfolio. Here is an idea of the project I am proposing:

I want to create a website that will have the capability to be used as a database for employees, where employees can be added and deleted. Then using the employee objects, a person (namely the secretary) could directly schedule a pickup or dropoff to a car service for that specific employee. For example: Employee A needs to be driven to Airport A on XX/XX/XXXX at YY:YY and picked up from Airport B on XX/XX/XXXX at YY:YY. This will then send the request to a car service company and schedule the pickup or dropoff.

My question is what database should I use to hold sensitive information which can be processed at fairly quick times. I'm assuming I would use something along the lines of HTML5/CSS/JS to create a front-end however I am unsure of what back-end to use. I reviewed the pros and cons of back-ends like Ruby on Rails and Django, however I am not sure which framework I should begin using.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for StackOverflow.  It's vague and calls for subjective, speculative, or highly opinionated answers.  See the help topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.  Please note that I am *not* saying that this isn't a good question, only that it's not appropriate for this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend, depending on language:

Simple front:

- Structure(html, css): Bootstrap framework, foundation, semantic ui
- Javascript: jQuery(must-have for bootstrap anyway), underscore, moment(for date/time) - this should fit your needs for that type of app

Best front:

- Above plus following:
- MVC Frameworks: angular, knockout, ember, backbone

Back-end:

- Database: MySql(maybe you are familiar already), MongoDB
- Php frameworks: Laravel(my choice), phalcon(fastest on planet), symfony, codeigniter
- Python frameworks: Django
- Ruby: Ruby on rails, roots
- Node(javascript on server): express.js, total.js

Automation:

-Grunt or Gulp ( i recommend Grunt )

Package management: Every language has its own, but:
- Front: bower
- Back: Composer(php)

My stack for your app:
Simple front + angular + laravel or node(if u wanna javascript on server)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have knowledge in Java maybe you should check the [play framework](http://playframework.com). It uses modern approachs for web development.

But if you want a more agile development both django or ruby on rails have almost equivalent power to do whatever you want very fast. So I recomend you to use the one you're more confortable with.

For database I recommend postgresql.